# What is the difference between "bildrakonto" and "komikso"?

Tags: word-difference

I have seen these two words used interchangeably in Reddit, however in French, there is a clear distinction between *bande dessinée* (any kind of comic strip) and *comics* (specific kind of comic strips who originated in the United States, with its own style and often involving superheroes). We would never call a manga a comics. Is there any kind of distinction between "bildrakonto" and "komikso" in Esperanto?

Answer (score 4):

According to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#komikso), *komikso* is synonymous to *bildrakonto*, and I have not seen a differentiation in practice, although I don't encouter these words very often.